# saleor checkout app with error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Tags: saleor

I've been trying to setup the checkout app for some days now, using the saleor-platform, went over the steps to run the project and I have everything running, and I've imported the app with ngrok and saleor app tunnel 3001 but with both I get

```
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start: { 'req.headers.origin': undefined }
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16)
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start:     at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start:   errno: -111,
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start:   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start:   syscall: 'connect',
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start:   address: '127.0.0.1',
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start:   port: 443
saleor-app-checkout          | saleor-app-checkout:start: }
```

when I go into the Settings page in the checkout app, aka. here
[image]

The only env variable I've played around chaning is [this](https://github.com/saleor/react-storefront/blob/1ff65ecca7797df5fbd70c4e6a9f5e4ea5455148/.env#L1) one(what should the env variable be here for local development?). I've also tried setting up the .auth_token file with the checkout app token but this didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Jonatan, one of the contributors of this react-storefront.
For local development, you'd need to tunnel both:

- the app [`saleor-app-checkout`](https://github.com/saleor/react-storefront/tree/436ac1328af2fbe784890969efb6bc1d9eb1c573/apps/saleor-app-checkout) (like you did by using our [CLI tool](https://github.com/saleor/saleor-cli): `saleor app tunnel 3001`)
- your local Saleor instance (you could use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for that: `ngrok http 8000`)

Once both the app and Saleor are accessible from the Internet, you'll have to:

1. Change the [`SALEOR_API_URL`](https://github.com/saleor/react-storefront/blob/canary/docs/development.md#env-variables) env variable inside the `.env` file to the URL of your tunneled Saleor instance (e.g. `https://1234.eu.ngrok.io/graphql/`)
2. Update [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.saleor.io/docs/3.x/setup/configuration#allowed_hosts) env variable in Saleor to include ngrok tunnel URL. In case of `saleor-platfrom` you'd have to update the [`docker-compose.yaml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers). It would look something like this:

```yaml
services:
  api:
    # ...
    environment:
      - JAEGER_AGENT_HOST=jaeger
      - STOREFRONT_URL=http://localhost:3000/
      - DASHBOARD_URL=http://localhost:9000/
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost,api,1234.eu.ngrok.io # <-- add tunnel domain here
```

When you do all that, restart both the app in `react-storefront` repository (`npm run dev`) and Saleor in Docker Compose (`docker compose down && docker compose up -d api worker`).

If you don't want to deal with creating a local Saleor instance, you could create a free sandbox instance in Saleor Cloud instead:

```
saleor storefront create --demo
```

In case you have more issues with the app, please refer to the documentation [inside the repository](https://github.com/saleor/react-storefront/blob/canary/docs/faq.md) or create a [new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/saleor/react-storefront/issues).

Comment: thank you for the detailed explaination, I will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Saleor is a open source project, it is a good idea to raise issue on github to seek advice from contributors

Comment: I did that, also if I'm not mistaken they adviced to ask questions here with their tag.